# C++ passing class instance between files

Tags: c++, file, class

*How can I access test.a from main?*
Here is my code:

**myfile1.cpp:**

```
#include "myfile2.h"
int main()
{
    test.a=1; //this gives error "incomplete type is not allowed"
}
```

**myfile2.h:**

```
class abc;
abc test;
```

**myfile2.cpp:**

```
#include "myfile2.h"

class abc{
public:
    int a;
    abc():
    a(0){}
} test;
```

Comment: First, cut everything in myfile2.cpp (except `#include`) and paste it to myfile2.h. That's how you get a complete type. If you want to split declaration and definition, google it.

Comment: I agree, downvotes without any explanation are not very helpful. That said, you are asking the compiler to compile "test.a=1" without assuring it that `test` *has* a member called `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *define* a variable of incomplete type, but you can *declare* one. If you don't want to make the class definition public, then you cannot access class members outside the translation unit where you define the class, so you also need to provide accessors. Here's a possible approach:

**header.h:**

```
class abc;                       // declares the name "abc"

extern abc test;                 // declares the name "test"

void set_a(abc & obj, int val);  // declares the name "set_a"
```

**impl.cpp:**

```
#include "header.h"

class abc { /* definition */ };

abc test;

void set_a(abc & obj, int val) { obj.a = val; }
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    set_a(test, 1);
}
```

Comment: since main have not seen the definition of `abc`, how will it know about the member `a`?

Comment: @sp2danny: Of course, you're right. I changed it so as to not require a public class definition.